# Need to inspect the Certificate Details attached with HTTP request

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I have attached a certificate with HTTP Client and wants to log the cert details just before or after sending the request to the server.

I tried below code but it is not working

`var cert = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(path)).Certificate;`

Can someone please help me with C# code snippet to get the cert details so that I can log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom HttpClientHandler and add logging logic inside the SendAsync method like this:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        foreach (var cert in ClientCertificates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cert.ToString(true));
        }

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        return response;
    }
}


var handler = new MyMessageHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertificateFromStore("CN=localhost"));
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```